# Как в pipline получить версию которую я указываю в тэге при коммите?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-runner, ci-cd

Я пишу pipline на gitlab и мне надо положить версию, которую я указываю в тэге при коммите таким образом: `git tag 1.8.21`
Раньше использовал команду для этого `$ TAG=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $CI_COMMIT_SHA)`
Но потом поменял gitlab-runner на тот который установил на компьютере своем и перестало работать, начало появляться вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом попробовал `$ TAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)` и получил все ту же ошибку. Можете пожалуйста посоветовать команду для получения версии?